# 302 redirect on url with plus in it

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect something like this but I just get a 404. All my others work except the ones with a + in them. I tried escaping the + as well but doesn't work.

```
RedirectMatch 302 /\+\123456788 https://example.com/
```

Comment: What URL are you going to and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @AmitVerma, it is going to https://example.com/+123456788 (which I assume was used for a telephone number but not done correctly as should be tel:+12345678) and that needs to redirect to the home page

Comment: @CBroe, should it then be `302 /\s123456788` ?

Comment: does it work? `RedirectMatch 302 /\+123456789 /`

Comment: @CBore thats a literal `+` char not the space

Comment: @AmitVerma, it seems that is working!

Comment: What is the the URL you are trying to match? You've only shown the directive/regex (which is incorrect). And if it's supposed to go "to `https://example.com/+123456788`" - then this directive is not going to do that.

Comment: @CBroe The `+` is only an encoded _space_ when used in the query string part of the URL. When used in the URL-path it's just a literal character.

Comment: @MrWhite, the url I am trying to match is `https://example.com/+123456788` and because it doesn't exist it should redirect to the home page `https://example.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, not tested it yet, should work I believe. We need to escape `+` to treat it as a literal character. Also we need not to escape 1 here since its a digit.

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/\+123456788/?$ https://example.com/
```

Comment: "not to escape 1" - Yes. Specifically, `\123` is seen as an octal escape sequence that matches a literal `S` (probably not what the OP intended).

Comment: @MrWhite, awesome, thank you for sharing(well I thought from regex point of view more that 1 is not having special meaning), that's a learning for me too, cheers.